# Difference between Seem and Look

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Is there any difference in meaning between seem and look?
For example, “He seems to be popular.” v. “He looks popular.”

Comment: You can seem anything. But if you look it, it should be something **you consider** visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He seems to be popular.

and

> He looks popular.

both mean that there is some impression that the person is popular. "Looks" is usually used when some visual information gave that impression, whereas "seems" is more generic. However, the use of "looks" for "seems" is somewhat idiomatic and may not be limited to visual things in all cases.